# Trafodion in cluster mode with spark

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I have developed spark application with trafodion. When running the application using `--master local[*]` mode using the spark-submit command then it's working fine and data is inserting in DB properly. But when I am running the same application in `--master yarn` cluster mode then it is not running. It is giving errors :

> ERROR[29716] Error writing to the certificate file
>   /home/hadoop-testing-M3_yarn.cer.
>
> ERROR[29716] Error writing to the certificate file
>   /home/hadoop-testing-M1_yarn.cer.
>
> ERROR[29716] Error writing to the certificate file
>   /home/hadoop-testing-M2_yarn.cer.

We have 3 node cluster and getting this error while running trafodion in cluster mode.

Could anyone tell me how can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to lack of write privileges to /home for yarn user. You can override the default location by specifying a directory in jdbc url where yarn user has permissions

"jdbc:t4jdbc://:23400/:certificateDir=/tmp"

Comment: URL should contain hostname name and port number "jdbc:t4jdbc://serverHostname:23400/:certificateDir=/tmp"